# Thermal Management Issue HP DV7

Tags: radeon, overheating

Computer: HP DV7 6b73nr

I've been having issues with my computer running hot on Ubuntu and other distros.  When I'm doing nothing, it's running 140-150 F (60-66 C).  Running `top` shows that there isn't much going on.

I have a Radeon hd 6770M, and I tried everything I could find on how to get the drivers working.  1 of 2 things happened.  Either the driver broke some of my graphics and the computer still ran hot or it would error and hang during boot.  I got tired of fighting the drivers and decided I would just turn the graphics card off.  I used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics to turn off the dedicated graphics.

No dice.  It still runs hot (and approaches overheating when I acutually do something)

I updated the BIOS, and have tried switching between dynamic and fixed graphics in BIOS.  Nothing seems to diminish the heat

I do not have any heat problems in Windows 7, and heating is an issue in the following distros (all amd64):

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Kubuntu 11.10
- Kubuntu 12.04
- Linux Mint 12
- Arch Linux
- KDE Fedora

Comment: I don't have a problem with my HP DV7 laptop, but it runs an nvidia card.  I also don't have problems with my ATI 5850 in my desktop.

Comment: @aking1012 can you post some more computer specs?  I want to try to narrow down the problems/differences

Comment: I find that having any flash running can really nuke my video card temperature on the linux side.  Even if the video is paused, off-screen, or whatever.  Just something I noticed.  I can drop a full set of system specs in chat or whatever, but it would be atrocious in comments and not really answer material.

Comment: With no GUI running on a test of arch, it was still running hot (though not quite as hot), so I think that there is a deeper problem with some hardware support or something.  Any ideas?

Comment: you could try manually setting fan speeds.  if the card has an associated fan: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=752282 ... if it doesn't http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also the issue and I did the migration to 12.04 and it's magic. It is solved.

Comment: Yes.  It seems like the problem is solved in 12.04.  Installing additional drivers for my graphics card via the GUI worked painlessly, and there hasn't been any overheating for twoish months

Answer (score 0):

there must the driver problem, or some sort of power control module/daemon/service missing or yet to be polished, that's the way the desktop computers are under Linux

Comment: Is there anything I can do in the mean time to try to get a working distro?  Or are there further tests that I can do to help out the community and figure out what isn't working?  I know that the drivers aren't working, but what about the ACPI or chipset or something. What are the procedures for troubleshooting those?  I ran `acpi_listen` and tried to check for versions and other signs that it was working, and wasn't getting any response